# Is there any way to pass email@ and password to Google APi OAuth2 without showing browser (i.e do it in background from a service for many accounts)?

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to implement a service that will be executed by my c# app. It will loop in a list of accounts(email, password) and try to get events from google calendar. Therefore, I need to create credentials fro each user using his email-pwd without showing the browser authentication window i.e without asking user to access, because this process is executed in background. How can I achieve this task?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code?

Comment: Firstly, i used Google Calendar API v3,  worked on it & created a small sample, but it enforces login & user consent screen to grant access to Calendar. that doesn' help me.I want to build a service backend, where no human interaction is possible. i tried also Google.GData.Client but the login doesn't work i think it's deprecated.

Comment: public static CalendarService GetService(string applicationName,
                string userName, string password)
                {
            CalendarService service = new CalendarService(applicationName);
            service.setUserCredentials(userName, password);
            return service;
        }      i need to do that with Google Calendar Api v3, is it possible??

Comment: I would like to clarify if you want to use Google Calendar API without authentication? Please edit your post and include the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have user interaction (through a browser) at some point but you could at that point also request "offline" access - which means that Google will issue a long-lived refresh token that you can use to retrieve a new access token when the old one expires.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass email@ and password to Google APi OAuth2 without showing the

consent screen. Google Api doesn't provide the ability to any thirdparty to do that. So i

must pass by the the consent screen to authentify my users.